# how to ggplot the CDF of multiple variables in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, cdf, ecdf

I have the the `DF` `data.frame`. I want to `plot` the `cumulative distribution function (CDF)` of the `variables` in `DF` using `ggplot`. using the following code produce the `plot` but because of big range in the data for `variables` i don't see the `plot` well. I don't want to use `multiple facets`- would like to have all of the `variables` `plotted` on the `single panel`.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

DF <- melt(data.frame(p1 = runif(200,1,10), p2 = runif(200,-2,1), p3 = runif(200,0,0.05),p4 = runif(200,100,4000)))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = value, col = variable))+
  stat_ecdf(lwd = 1.2)
```

Comment: Facets are the obvious solution, but setting alpha might help slightly

Answer (score 2):

We can use `facet_wrap` to identify

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = value, col = variable))+
   stat_ecdf(lwd = 1.2) +
   facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use facets, you could use a log scale:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

DF <- reshape::melt(data.frame(p1 = runif(200,1,10), p2 = runif(200,-2,1), p3 = runif(200,0,0.05),p4 = runif(200,100,4000)))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = value, col = variable),log='x')+
  stat_ecdf(lwd = 1.2)+
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]